# Get attributibutes in only base class (Python)

Tags: python, inheritance

I have the following class structures:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def print_vars(self):
        print(vars(self))

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, id, name, last_name, age):
       Parent.__init__(self, id, name)
       self.last_name = last_name
       self.age = age

class AnotherChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self, id, name, address):
       Parent.__init__(self, id, name)
       self.address= address
```

Perhaps not the best example, but I hope enough to get the idea accross. The idea is that I initialise two seperate instances that share some common attributes and methods. I need to be able to dump both objects into some json and csv files which I hope to achieve with the method `dump_to_file` (replaced by `print_vars` in this example). Now this method worked fine when I had to dump all the attributes from both the parent and child classes to a single file. Howeer, I want to only dump the attributes from the parent class. I tried to replace `self` by `super` or `super(Parent, self)` but without much success. What is the best way to access *only* the attributes from the class the code is written in?

I believe Java would do this automatically as the method is defined in the parent class, and the parent class does not know the child class attributes.

Comment: why not simply create an object of parent and then call the method.

Comment: because the values of the variables may be different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you aren't going to add more variables outside `__init__`, you could freeze the list of variables in the `__init__` method of the parent:

```
def __init__(self, id, name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.__parent_vars = dict(vars(self))  # make a copy
```

then use this dictionary, which has only the variables you defined when you initialized the parent class:

```
def print_values(self, path):
    print(self.__parent_vars)
```

testing:

```
c = Child(12,"Foo","whatever",34)
c.print_vars()
```

I get:

```
{'id': 12, 'name': 'Foo'}
```

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre♦ I add some modifications , can you take a look at it? Do I need to post new question?

Comment: yes, of course you should post the answer you made as a question, linking to this question, why not. But delete this answer which is not really an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem at current moment and trying to find solution.
[@Jean-François Fabre♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633293/4960953) 's answer can't solve my own problem - it freezes arguments values at the moment of initializing Child class and if it change in future your Child class never knows about it.

I made some modifications to fix it:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.__parent_vars = ['id', 'name']  # make a copy

    def print_values(self):
        res = {}
        for el in self.__parent_vars:
            res[el] = vars(self)[el]
        return res


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, id, name, last_name, age):
        Parent.__init__(self, id, name)
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
```

Lets test it:

```
c = Child(12,"Foo","whatever",34)
res1 = c.print_values()
print(res1)

c.id = 24
res2 = c.print_values()
print(res2)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 12, 'name': 'Foo'}
{'id': 24, 'name': 'Foo'}
```

Now it works as I expected BUT I need to create additioanl variable for it. So if I want to pickle, for example, my class it will also pickle this additional variable that I don't need. **Is it possible to do the same actions qwithout creating additional variable?**