# How to get attributes of parent class object only

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I have 2 classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.__parent_vars = ['id', 'name']  # make a copy

    def print_values(self):
        res = {}
        for el in self.__parent_vars:
            res[el] = vars(self)[el]
        return res


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, id, name, last_name, age):
        Parent.__init__(self, id, name)
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
```

What I want to do - is to get from `Child` parameters of `Parent` class. I made it using additional variable and it works, but I need more elegant solution without additional variable. I need it for pickle class. If I create additional variable it breaks my Schemas in a big project.

I try to find something like this:

```
c = Child(12,"Foo","whatever",34)
vars(c.super())
```

with expected output:

```
{'id': 12, 'name': 'Foo'}
```

---

I found this question: [Get attributibutes in only base class (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43633129/4960953) but it has significant difference of mine, so I can't use that solution.

Comment: They’re created by assigning to `self`, which is already a `Child`. Attributes don’t keep track of which function created them. You will need to continue defining which properties belong to the parent explicitly at least to some extent. (`self.__parent_vars = list(self.__dict__)` might be an option.)

Comment: @Ry- thank you for response! Did it mean it is impossible? Some `super` hints or something else? Or maybe some hints on creating some additional method but not field?

Comment: `vars(c)` prints: `{'id': 12,
 'name': 'Foo',
 '_Parent__parent_vars': ['id', 'name'],
 'last_name': 'whatever',
 'age': 34}`  instead  `c.print_values()`  `{'id': 12, 'name': 'Foo'}`

Comment: maybe in Child you should create new `print_values` which use `super().print_values()` to execute parent `print_values` and later add child values to parent values.

Comment: @MatteoPeluso yes, of course :) thats why I asked this question )

Comment: You seem to confuse class with object. Those aren't class attributes. They are instance (object) attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one more solution. It looks simplier, so I used it. It based on using [Marshmallow Schemas.](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
Also It is more usiful in my project because I already used marshmallow Schemas.
The idea: I create 2 classes and 2 different Schemas. And can serialize bigger class (Child) using just Parent schema:

## Code

#### Define 2 classes:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 'ID'
        self.name = 'some_name'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self.last_name = 'last_name'
        self.age = 15

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, EXCLUDE
```

#### Define 2 Schemas:

```
class ParentSchema(Schema):
    ba = Parent()
    id = fields.Str(missing=ba.id)
    name = fields.Str(missing=ba.name)

class ChildSchema(Schema):
    ba = Child()
    id = fields.Str(missing=ba.id)
    name = fields.Str(missing=ba.name)

    last_name = fields.Str(missing=ba.last_name)
    age = fields.Int(missing=ba.age)
```

#### use it to get only Parent attributes for Child object:

```
user_data = {'id':'IDIDID', 'name':'add_name', 'last_name':'FAMILIYA'}
res = ParentSchema().load(user_data, unknown=EXCLUDE)

# output:
res
{'name': 'add_name', 'id': 'IDIDID'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot easily. In Python, classes only carry methods and static attributes. Non 
static attributes are commonly stored in the `__dict__` attribute of the objects. That means that except in special cases, you cannot easily know which attributes where assigned in a parent class method, in a child class method or even outside any method.

I can only imagine a meta_class that would instrument the `__init__` method to store which attributes were changed during its call:

```
import collections
import functools
import inspect

class Meta_attr(type):
    init_func = {}
    attrs = collections.defaultdict(set)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        c = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds)
        cls.init_func[c] = c.__init__
        @functools.wraps(c.__init__)
        def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
            before = set(self.__dict__.keys())
            cls.init_func[c](self, *args, **kwargs)
            after = set(self.__dict__.keys())
            cls.attrs[c].update(after.difference(before))
        init.__signature__ = inspect.signature(c.__init__)
        c.__init__ = init
        return c

class Parent(object, metaclass=Meta_attr):
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def print_values(self):
        res = {}
        for el in Meta_attr.attrs[Parent]:
            res[el] = vars(self)[el]
        return res


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, id, name, last_name, age):
        Parent.__init__(self, id, name)
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
```

It gives:

```
>>> c = Child(1,"a","b", 20)
>>> c.print_values()
{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}
```

**BEWARE**: if an attribute is set outside of the `__init__` method, it will not be registered by this meta class...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As I see it solves the problem, but look like it is easy to use additional filed `__parent_vars` :D

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam: metaclasses are a very powerful tool that allows to go rather deep inside the internal Python machinery. It is often used in large frameworks to provide a constistent API for user defined classes but I am not sure that it is worth it here. Only you can say that...

Comment: I found one more solution. Take a look please.