# How to access only the attributes from parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributes

I am trying to write a method of a parent class, that allows any child of that class to return *only* the attributes defined as part of the parent class. I can think of some hacky/hardcodey ways around this (using `__dict__`) but would like to know the more pythonic/proper way of doing it.

An example of what I'd be trying to do would be like this:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, var1=1, var2=2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def get_parent_attrs(self):
        # magic
        return dict_of_attrs

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var3=3, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.var3 = var3
```

So it can be used like this:

```
child = Child(var1='a', var2='b', var3='c')
child.get_parent_attrs()
>>> {'var1':'a', 'var2':'b'}
```

or more specifically like this:

```
class OtherChild(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var4=4, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.var4 = var4

    def create_sibling(self, var3):
        return Child(var3=var3, **self.get_parent_attrs())


other_child = OtherChild(var1='a', var2='b', var4='d')
sibling = other_child.create_sibling(var3='c')
```

I may be thinking down the wrong path at the mo, so perhaps it's better if I state my problem like this: How can I write a method in a child class that allows me to instantiate other classes (that inherit from the same parent) with the parent attributes used to instantiate the original child class?

EDIT:
I think I found a solution via [Get attributibutes in only base class (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633129/get-attributibutes-in-only-base-class-python)
which stores the parent attrs in a variable. Will see if this works, and update/close my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the desired functionality after seeing the accepted answer on [How to get attributes of parent class object only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883180/how-to-get-attributes-of-parent-class-object-only?noredirect=1&lq=1), which used marshmallow. Additionally it turns out for my specific problem it actually makes more sense with dataclasses and desert.

Below is an example of how I've solved my specific issue, but since it doesn't answer the more general question I posed, I won't accept it as the answer.

```
import desert
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass
from marshmallow import EXCLUDE, fields

@dataclass
class Parent:
    var1: int = dataclasses.field(
        metadata=desert.metadata(
            fields.Int(
                missing=1
            )
        )
    )
    var2: int = dataclasses.field(
        metadata=desert.metadata(
            fields.Int(
                missing=2
            )
        )
    )

    def create_sibling(self, sibling_class, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = self.__dict__
        
        attrs = {**attrs, **kwargs}  
        
        schema = desert.schema(sibling_class, meta={'unknown': EXCLUDE})
        return schema.load(attrs)

@dataclass
class Child(Parent):
    var3: int = dataclasses.field(
        metadata=desert.metadata(
            fields.Int(
                missing=3
            )
        )
    )
    


@dataclass
class OtherChild(Parent): 
    var4: int = dataclasses.field(
        metadata=desert.metadata(
            fields.Int(
                missing=4
            )
        )
    )

child = Child(var1=5, var2=6, var3=7)
other_child = child.create_sibling(OtherChild, var4=8)

print(other_child)
>>> OtherChild(var1=5, var2=6, var4=8)


# or with desert again to handle default params
schema = desert.schema(Child)
child = schema.load({})
other_child = child.create_sibling(OtherChild, var4=8)
print(other_child)
>>> OtherChild(var1=1, var2=2, var4=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is was what you were going for, but here's how you could achieve it :

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, var1:str='', var2:str = ''):
        self.Var1 = var1
        self.Var2 = var2

    def get_parent_attrs(self):
        # magic
        print('Attributes of parent class are : ' + str(self.Var1) + ' and ' + str(self.Var2))

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,var1:str='', var2:str = '',var3:str=''):
        super().__init__(var1,var2)
        self.var3 = var3



child = Child('a','b','c')
child.get_parent_attrs()
```

in this scenario, we get: Variables of parent class are : a and b

Comment: I'm afraid I was looking for something that would return a dictionary of only the attrs associated with the Parent class, so that I could use it to instantiate another object that also inherits from the same Parent, and would not require hardcoding parent class attributes specifically.